# Boosting for regression systems

Tags: regression, boosting

I am quite a newbie in this area:

- What are the boosting methods for regression systems? I know about [Gradient boosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting); are there any other approaches?
- Are there textbooks or tutorials devoted to this area?

Answer (score 4):

While I haven't seen anything specifically, I doubt that it would achieve much, at least for linear regression. Each regression equation is just a linear combination of the predictors:
$$\hat{y}^{(j)} = \sum_i \hat{\beta}_i^{(j)} x_i$$
Most boosting algorithms in turn combine multiple predictors by taking a weighted average, which is another linear combination:
$$\hat{y} = \sum_j \hat{w}^{(j)} \hat{y}^{(j)}$$
 So the final output is still a linear combination of the predictors, only with the coefficients obtained by a complicated process.

Comment: yeah but it might do well for logistic regression.